# Change background color of selected items in "multiselect" dropdown box?

Tags: css, multi-select, html.dropdownlistfor

I want to give the yellow color to the selected items in multiselect dropdown box. By default, it has gray background after selecting,
How to do this in `HTML`, `CSS`.

This question is about **multiselect** but for single select refer (Related but not duplicate of either): [How to apply background-color to a selected option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18091866)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use JS to select the DOMs.

```
$('select').change(function() {
    $('option').css('background', 'none');
    $('option:selected').css('backgroundColor', 'red');
}).change()

<select>
    <option>1111111</option>
    <option>222222222</option>
    <option>33333333</option>
    <option>44444444</option>
</select>
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/TxbVt/1/

Answer (score 7):

We can simply do with the help of the below CSS:

```
select option:checked{
  background: #1aab8e -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #1aab8e 0%, #1aab8e 100%);
}
```

Comment: Does anyone have any idea why this works but background: #1aab8e; doesn't?

Answer (score 2):

```
<style>
     .select2-container--default .select2-results__option[aria-selected=true] {
        background-color: inherit;
        color: lightgray;
    }
</style>
```

Add your own style inside the block.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work *(for browsers that allow styling option tags)*, however the default select styling will override in most cases. You may be able to find a way to disable this however:

- http://jsfiddle.net/DEDX7/
- http://jsfiddle.net/DEDX7/1/

*css*

```
select option.selected {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}
```

*javascript*

```
function highlight_options(field){
  var i,c;
  for(i in field.options){
    (c=field.options[i]).className=c.selected?'selected':'';
  }
}
```

*markup*

```
<select onchange="highlight_options(this)" multiple="multiple">
  <option>One</option>
  <option>Two</option>
  <option>Three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @VicKyAmr Yeah unfortunately as I said. by the looks of it you can't remove this... at least as far as I've found. All because the highlight isn't a property of the option element, it is a layer on top. However, you can still affect styles that aren't overridden though... like border and padding. And you can apply styles and background images to the non-selected options as well to make them more appealing.

Answer (score -2):

Pure CSS would help here:

```
option:checked
```

Answer (score -3):

You can't. The `<option>` element does not accept CSS styling.

You can used a JavaScript-based alternative. There are many `<select>` replacement scripts available.

Comment: Not true 100% I'm afraid... modern browsers do allow this. Try it in FireFox ;) it's not cross browser reliable however.

Comment: Thanks @Diodeus, Can you hel me with the Javascript to style as below.
**selected { /* Text colour and font weight, red and bold */
color:blue;
font-weight:bold;
}**

Comment: JavaScript cannot do this with a standard select item. See: http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/07/28/reinventing-drop-down-with-css-jquery.aspx

Comment: Oh, I need like this one http://jsfiddle.net/TxbVt/1/
It also not working as you mentioned @Diodeus