# How to apply background-color to a selected option?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm writing a dropdown menu with several options and their colors. I have successfully colored the background of each option; however, once selected that background color doesn't show.

Is there a way to change this behavior? Example of my HTML below:

```
<select>
  <option style="background-color: green">Successful</option>
  <option style="background-color: orange">Process Failure</option>
  <option style="background-color: purple">Abandoned</option>
</select>
```

or also here: http://jsfiddle.net/H8HVm/1/.

Comment: I think you need javscript manipulation to do this.

Comment: You'll need to apply the `background-style` to the `<select>` tag as well. As far as doing it dynamically, using JS/Jquery is your best bet. I'm working on something now and will post soon...

Comment: @KatieK OP is trying to change the color of the `<select>` tag, not the `<option>`. He/she is also trying to make the color dependent on what selection is made so I'd say this isn't a dupe of what you suggested.

Comment: @KatieK, although select is in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14168650/multi-select-box-selected-background-color-css) post, my question has to do with the <select> tag, not a box selection.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use jQuery to read the `class` of the selected `option` then set that `class` as the `class` of the `<select>`. Here is the code, followed by a fiddle:

```js
$("#color_me").change(function(){
    var color = $("option:selected", this).attr("class");
    $("#color_me").attr("class", color);
});
```

```css
.green {
    background-color: green;
}
.orange {
    background-color: orange;
}
.pink {
    background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="color_me" class="">
    <option class="green">successful</option>
    <option class="orange">process failure</option>
    <option class="pink">abandoned</option>
</select>
```

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DrydenLong/3QUN6/

Per request, here is a breakdown of my code above:

```
$("#color_me").change(function(){
```

This line calls function when the element with the `id` of "color_me" is changed. i.e. an option from the select list is chosen.

```
    var color = $("option:selected", this).attr("class");
```

This defines the variable `color` as whatever the `class` of the current selected `option` is. The `this` variable is referring to the DOM element we referenced in the first line. Basically `this` ensures that we are getting the class from the correct `<select>` i.e. the `<select>` we just clicked on.

```
    $("#color_me").attr("class", color);
});
```

This line assigns the `color` variable defined above as the `class` of the element with the `id` of `#color_me`.

Comment: @HashemQolami Nice! Always a +1 for pure JS. JS Bin doesn't work well for me on Chrome so I made a fiddle of your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/DrydenLong/TUBKk/

Comment: Classy! Exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

```js
var x, i, j, selElmnt, a, b, c;
x = document.getElementsByClassName("tt-select");

for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    selElmnt = x[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
    a = document.createElement("DIV");
    a.setAttribute("class", "select-selected");
    a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
    x[i].appendChild(a);
    b = document.createElement("DIV");
    b.setAttribute("class", "select-items select-hide");
    for (j = 0; j < selElmnt.length; j++) {
        /*for each option in the original select element,
        create a new DIV that will act as an option item:*/
        c = document.createElement("DIV");
        c.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[j].innerHTML;
        c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            var y, i, k, s, h;
            s = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
            h = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
            for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
                if (s.options[i].innerHTML == this.innerHTML) {
                    s.selectedIndex = i;
                    h.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
                    y = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("same-as-selected");
                    for (k = 0; k < y.length; k++) {
                        y[k].removeAttribute("class");
                    }
                    this.setAttribute("class", "same-as-selected");
                    break;
                }
            }
            h.click();
        });
        b.appendChild(c);
    }
    x[i].appendChild(b);
    a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        closeAllSelect(this);
        this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("select-hide");
        this.classList.toggle("select-arrow-active");
    });
}
function closeAllSelect(elmnt) {
    var x, y, i, arrNo = [];
    x = document.getElementsByClassName("select-items");
    y = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");
    for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
        if (elmnt == y[i]) {
            arrNo.push(i)
        } else {
            y[i].classList.remove("select-arrow-active");
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (arrNo.indexOf(i)) {
            x[i].classList.add("select-hide");
        }
    }
}
document.addEventListener("click", closeAllSelect);
```

```css
.tt-select {
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    text-align: left;
}
.tt-select select {
    display: none;
}
.select-selected {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) !important;
}
.select-selected:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: 14px;
    right: 10px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 6px solid transparent;
}
.select-selected:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: 18px;
    right: 10px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 6px solid transparent;
    border-color: transparent transparent #000000 transparent;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.select-selected.select-arrow-active:before {
    border: none;
}
.select-selected.select-arrow-active:after {
    border-color: transparent transparent #000000 transparent;
    top: 10px;
}
.select-items div,.select-selected {
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    border: 1px solid #333333;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.select-items {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #313131;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 99;
}
.select-hide {
    display: none;
}
.select-items div:hover, .same-as-selected {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="tt-select">
    <select>
        <option value="0">Options</option>
        <option value="1">Option One</option>
        <option value="2">Option Two</option>
        <option value="3">Option Three</option>
        <option value="4">Option Four</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Here is a [CodePen link](https://codepen.io/afsar-uddin/pen/XPMBpo).

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").change(function(){
        var color = $("option:selected", this).attr("class");
        $(this).attr("class", color);
    });
});
</script>
```